# Rails, ActiveRecord and SubQueries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, subquery, rails-postgresql

I have a postgresql database with hourly gas consumption entries.
Now, I need to find the days with the highest consumption for every month.

In plain SQL I'd use subqueries like this:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC('month', day) AS month,
    MAX(dailyconsumption) as maxconsumption
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DATE_TRUNC('day', date) AS day,
        SUM(consumption) AS dailyconsumption
    FROM Records
    GROUP BY day
) t
GROUP BY month
```

However, I don't know the best way (or any way) to do this in rails. I appreciate any input. Should I bypass ActiveRecord? Performance is a high priority.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your subquery should be recreated with something like:

```
subquery = Records
  .all
  .select("DATE_TRUNC('day', date) AS day", "SUM(consumption) AS dailyconsumption")
  .group("day")
```

To query from a subquery, instead of a table, you use `from`.

```
Records.select(...).from(subquery)
```

Note that `subquery` is an ActiveRecord relation. Not actual data. It gets converted to SQL in the second statement and the whole thing is run on the DB side.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about '.from'. Where is the beste place to define these subqueries? The Controller?

Comment: @potofski where is the "best" to put them is up for debate. Current Rails practices suggest keeping the controller as minimal as possible and doing work in the model.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is high priority then consider using a View, a view can be represented in Active Record as regular Model, you could even consider using a Materialized View and periodically update the records, that way you won't need to calculate everything every single time.

See the [scenic gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/scenic) for adding views and materialized views as part of your migrations.